# In the sentence "How did John do?", should the verb "do" be replaced with "does"?

Tags: grammaticality, verb-forms

While giving my exam online, there was a comparison with John. There I found one sentence:

> How did John do?

Is it right grammatically? I think John is one person so *does* should be used. Please explain.

Comment: Did you mean "While taking my exam online..."? For example, the instructor "gives" the exam, and the students "take" the exam. It seems to me it should be that way, because if you were giving the exam, I suppose you would already know the questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sentence is correct; it is the construction of questions in English. With **did** in past tense you use the **do** form.

Similarly, you say:

> How **did** he **manage** to win the race?

That is true with **does/present tense** also, for example with:

> How **does** Federer **play** 5 sets without getting tired?

While replying the above mentioned rule of s/es will apply.

> He **plays** with exceptionally good technique.

Comment: Accounting for playing five [setters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Setter) without getting tired probably requires knowledge of the setters' ages and breeds, rather than of Federer's technique